# wait(0.5) is there a way? --fflush() block stop stdin?

Tags: c, input, io, pthreads, wait

The objective is to make `workin()` a low priority thread while other really heavy calculations are being made.

Is there a way to make a `wait()` of, lets say, 0.5 seconds?

Is it possible to block incoming characters to terminal while on `wait()`? because it messes up with the characters printed to "processing ... " this part is solved, see solution below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *workin(){
    int i=0,count=10;
    char v[]={' ',' ','-','-','-',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};

    for(;;){
        for(i=count-1;i>=0;i--){
            v[(i+1)%(count)]=v[i];
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\r");
        printf("processing ");
        printf("%s ",v);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_t tid;  
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,workin,NULL);

    sleep(15);/*HEAVY stuff here*/

    pthread_cancel(tid);
    printf("\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Half solved, missing `wait(0.5)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>

char getch(){
    /*#include <unistd.h>   //_getch*/
    /*#include <termios.h>  //_getch*/
    char buf=0;
    struct termios old = {0};
    fflush(stdout);
    if(tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag&=~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag&=~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
    if(tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if(read(0,&buf,1)<0)
        perror("read()");
    old.c_lflag|=ICANON;
    old.c_lflag|=ECHO;
    if(tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
        perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");

    return buf;
}

void *workin(){
    int i=0,count=10;

    char v[]={' ',' ','>','>','>',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};

    for(;;){
        for(i=count-1;i>=0;i--){
            v[(i+1)%(count)]=v[i];
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("processing ");
        printf("%s ",v);
        printf("\r");
        sleep(1);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char ch=0;

    pthread_t tid;  
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,workin,NULL);

    do{
        ch=getch();/*HEAVY CALCULATIONS HERE*/
    }while(1);

    pthread_cancel(tid);
    printf("\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have learned to "flush" `stdin` is to read from it and discard the information.

The way I have found to do a `wait()` of half a second (0.5s) is using:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

usleep(500000);
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to pass a particular thread outputs to a terminal( opened mannually) like writing to a file content

Comment: FILE *f;
    f = fopen("/dev/pts/2", "w");          ///"dev/pts/2" be another terminal            
    printf("f: %d\n",f);          
    fprintf(f,"line\n");

Comment: any way to know the number of terminals already opened ?? because right now i have 3(0,1,2) and that failed